# Firefox support for alignment-baseline property?

Tags: css, svg

Does Firefox have any support at all for the [`alignment-baseline` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline)?  When I inspect (using Firebug) SVG elements for which the `alignment-baseline` property has been explicitly set, Firebug does not list this property at all (IOW it treats is as noise).  No matter what value I assign to this property, the appearance of the displayed text never changes, further suggesting that FF ignores this property altogether.

(One other sign that FF's support for this property may be busted is that the link given in the page cited above for the CSS documentation for this property is [dead-as-a-doornail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/alignment-baseline).)

Assuming that, as it appears, FF does not support the `alignment-baseline` property, what is the value of this property that would most closely replicate FF's default behavior?

EDIT: For example, view this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/APWE3/3/) with both Chrome and FF; each line of displayed text displayed a highlighted word that has been produced with code of the following form:

```
<tspan style="alignment-baseline:alphabetic">alphabetic</tspan>
```

Note that all the lines look the same in FF, but not so in Chrome.

There are a few possible candidate values for this property to replicate FF's default behavior (namely, `auto`, `alphabetic`, `mathematic`, and `inherit`); unfortunately, this experiment cannot decide the matter, and it's not clear to me which of the possible options would match FF's default behavior in the greatest fraction of cases.

Answer (score 53):

It seems that `alignment-baseline` is ment to be used only for portions of `<text>`, that is for elements `tspan`, `tref` etc. For the main `<text>` element use the `dominant-baseline` attribute.

(This is what @Tanel Eero wrote above as a comment. I'm re-stating it here so the question can get an accepted answer).

Comment: This saved me another few hours of beating my head on my desk.

Comment: me too, thanks you guys for making my day great again :)

Answer (score 11):

The Mozilla Developer Network website states that the style can only be used on certain elements:

> The following elements can use the alignment-baseline attribute
>
> ```
> <tspan>
> <tref>
> <altglyph>
> <textpath>
> ```

So that seems to be your main issue as I understand that you are trying to apply it to a SVG.

Comment: thanks; please see the jsFiddle I've referred to in my latest EDIT

Comment: I see what you mean. I guess the css page link at the bottom of the developer network page speaks for itself. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/alignment-baseline

Comment: Actually I just found this one - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=SVG%2FAttribute%2Fdominant-baseline

Seems to work in you fiddle, but I'm not sure if it does what you are looking for.

Comment: I suppose a main source of confusion here is that (right now, maybe also some 4 years ago) the *Example* section and the *live sample* on the very same [MDN doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline) apply the `alignment-baseline` attribute to `<text>` elements, even though explicitly stating in the next paragraph that's not supposed to be possible. At to that that it appears to work in Chrome in spite of everything, and the confusion is complete.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The codepen on MDN doesn't work in Firefox either when you put a tspan inside it and give it the attribute. Very confusing.