# Center text in a SVG

Tags: svg

I've this code:

```html
<svg style="background:pink">
  <style type="text/css">
      .text {
          font-family:'Arial';
          font-size:92px;
          color: #000000;
      }
  </style>
  <text class="text" x="20" y="82">Your text</text>
</svg>
```

How it's possible to remove the `x` and `y` and center the text ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52719480/421195.  Please post back whether or not it worked for you.

Comment: **1**. your svg element has no viewBox and no size defined making it 300px/150px. **2**. In order to center the text make the x="150" (in the middle of the actual svg canvas 300px wide) and add `text-anchor="middle"` **3**. Your font is too big so it will be cropped outside the svg canvas. You may need to change the size of the font.

Comment: There are a zillion solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546346/how-to-place-and-center-text-in-an-svg-rectangle